# Steal This Comic

Tags: visual, steganography

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. Is this a puzzle or just an xkcd comic?

Comment: @Joe I'd assume there's something hidden in this image, especially given the tags.

Comment: Got it, I thought the steganography tag was perhaps referring to hidden html in the post, but I'm searching through the image now.

Comment: *You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all alike.*

Comment: @Rubio *Each one more identical than the last.*

Comment: This has been one of my favorite puzzles ever. I really enjoyed the group effort to get the final answer. I think gnovice deserves the accepted answer. He did the most work.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Appreciate that.  It turned out apparently more difficult than I expected.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Final answer:

When comparing the image above to the [original comic](https://xkcd.com/488/), we can see that...

> the text "DRM-free files" at the bottom right is replaced by "0XAmp" (a zero, not an O). Using this instead of "kLvQR" for the post image link leads us to [this new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XAmp.png), which has five letters that differ from the original comic:
>
>   [image]
>
>  The letters "KRODF" become "WVNZ2". The correct order is "V2ZNW", with the characters ordered based on their position in their respective text blocks ("W" is the fifth character, "V" is the first character, etc.). Using this in the image link leads to a new image:
>
>   [image]
>
>   If we replace each number `5 8 -5 13 42` with the character at that position in each text block, not counting spaces or non-alphanumeric characters, and assuming negative means counting starting at the end and making it lowercase, then we get "KRiR0". Using this in the image link leads to a new image:
>
>   [image]
>
>  On the surface, this doesn't appear to differ from the original comic, but if you adjust the intensity you can see some ghosted text appear. I processed the image in MATLAB using the code `imwrite(uint8(255.*(imread('KRiR0.png') > 245)), 'adjusted.png');` to get this:
>
>   [image]
>
>  And the characters "EdxNK" (read from top to bottom) appear. Using this in the image link leads to [a new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdxNK.png) with 5 changed letters (4 lower-cased and one removed):
>
>   [image]
>
>   And finally, using "goioF" in the image link leads to the final image:
>
>   [image]

Phew! All that image stealing made me tired! Thanks to everyone who was solving it alongside me!

Comment: We're at the same point :-) I think that the second thing you've called Z is actually 2, if that helps? (Again, compare with the "2" of "DMCA 1201".)

Comment: @Randal'Thor: You're right, the second one does look more two-ish.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Unfortunately there was no Z in the text.  However, anytime I could, I grabbed the letters from somewhere in the comic.

Comment: For the order of the characters in your second image, check where they appear in their respective text blocks.  Kudos for brute-forcing, though.

Comment: @gnovice, I think the Rot13: ahzoref ersre gb gur yrggre jr arrq gb trg arkg onfrq ba gur ahzore bs punenpgref va gung yvar

Comment: I tried assuming the numbers were how many characters into the sentence we need to go.  If we considered a new line as a character and the -5 starts at the end of pirate and works backward that gave K, U, I, R, I.  If we don't assume the new line is a character it gives K, U, M, R, I.  Trying all permutations of those letters only gives two hits with actual images but neither seem like they are what it should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIRKI.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/URIKM.png

Comment: [+1, as is customary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/216712).

Comment: @Dason Given how the progression is established, you could probably only count the characters that could be used.  You might also consider why one of them would be negative.

Comment: @Dason Also, I think you may have miscounted on the second one.  That's supposed to be an 8.

Comment: It looks like @Dason didn't miscount on the second one, he just listed them in an unusual order: 5 13 42 8 -5.  Also, he counted every character including spaces.

Comment: @gnovice, It almost looks like this last clue is the original comic. I can't find any obvious changes at least. Could this be the end of the riddle?

Comment: I can definitely see very light colored letters in areas, such as on the top person's face and just above the lower person's hat.

Comment: I just used a website to highlight the differences, and there are very clearly 5 letters.
https://online-image-comparison.com (use fuzz level 4)

Comment: You're right, I can definetely see the letter N

Comment: @Joe-You-Know It's fairly obvious when the end is reached.  Just in case there's unrelated links found, all the images are the same dimensions.

Comment: Does this mean anything to anyone? https://i.stack.imgur.com/dExNk.png

Comment: Found it, https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdxNK.png

Comment: @Joe-You-Know: Found it too. ;)

Comment: @gnovice Beat me to the end by seconds

Answer (score 8):

**Answer**:
After following a series of clues and finding the differences of the last one, you end up with

> [image]

As the final picture.
(I'll update my answer to reflect this)

Update:
Found this,

> [image]

From the work gnovice has been doing.

1st Answer

Okay, I'm not sure if this is just spot the difference but here it is

> In the original XKCD, the bottom line read "(If you don't like this, demand DRM-Free files)"
> In this puzzle, it instead reads, "(If you don't like this, demand OXAmp), which is as far as I can tell is an [anti-bacterial](https://www.ndrugs.com/?s=oxamp#doctor_indications)"
> Compare
>  [image]
>  
> To
> [image]
>  I feel there is more to this puzzle than just this difference, hopefully this will help others though.

Comment: Just to clarify, the "O" is a "0", specifically the one from the 1201.

Answer (score 7):

Joe-You-Know spotted the key difference between the image in the OP and the original XKCD comic:

> the replacement of "DRM-free files" by "0XAMP", with the MP smaller than the 0XA.

This suggests

> looking at https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XAmp.png - where we find:
>
>   [image: new image]

In this new image, we can again spot the key differences from the original XKCD comic:

> the letters K, R, O, D, F at various points have been replaced by W, V, N, ?, 2. I'm not sure what that fourth character is - R? Z? - or which of these are supposed to be lower-case, but presumably these letters will lead us to the next image.

Comment: V guvax gur zvffvat yrggre vf n m

Comment: @Joe That's one of my possibilities too, but it doesn't seem to give a working URL.

Comment: I thought maybe it was using rot13 for the next image, wvnnzz, but no luck there either

Comment: The ordering of the characters is there, you just need to determine how it's hidden.

Comment: @ffao I think you may have flipped a couple characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using

> V2ZNW

you get this image:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ZNW.png]

This shows some numbers. If you add them to the letter positions I get this:

> k(11) + 5 = p(16)
>
>  r(18) + 8 = z(26)
>
>  o(15) + 13 = 28 = b(2)
>
>  d(4) - 5 = -1 = y(25)
>
>  f(6) + 42 = 48 = v(22)

> This means `pzbyv`. Not sure what I can do with this ...

> If you rot13 this you get `comli`, maybe a misspelled comic?

Comment: The -5 should come before the 13, no need to add number positions, and a couple of your letters seem to be off (or I'm not understanding how you reached those letters).  For example, if I count 13 with spaces, I get the U in BUY, without spaces I get the R in DRM, but you have an O.

Comment: @DavidStarkey no, this is about their positions in the alphabet. And they are the letters you replaced with other characters in gnovices solution

Comment: But the 13th letter is M, so I'm still unsure how you got to O.

Comment: I think he's using 0 as A.

Comment: His KRODF comes from the previous step, when the letters KRODF were replaced by V2ZNW.  I think we can completely ignore those letters on this step.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake That makes much more sense.  Oddly coincidental that the first 2 letters are the same either way.